# Picking a number from a contact but removing the country code

Tags: android, android-edittext, number-formatting, mobile-country-code

I am able to get the contact phone number on button click then transfer it to an EditText, but I want only to get the result without the country code. Exemple : `+33 xx xx xx xxx becomes xx xx xx xxx`

Is there  a way I can achieve this?
The following code I use to get the number and put it in an EditText:

Button click:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
intent.setType(CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if ((requestCode == 1) && (resultCode == RESULT_OK)) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            Uri uri = data.getData();
            cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[] { CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER }, null, null, null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToNext()) {
                String phone = cursor.getString(0);
                editText.setText(phone);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [libphonenumber](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber) library from Google. Don't try to create your own logic, as format varies from location to location.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use replaceall. For example:
    `String phone = cursor.getString(0);
    phone = phone.replaceAll("+33", "");
    editText.setText(phone);`